# Update a wordpress template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates

I am using the lovecraft template of wordpress in order to setup my website. I want to change two things. Firstly i want to change the font of the menu and sub-menu (dropdown menu) of the template. Secondly, i want to move the post area in the way that is depicted in the following image:

[image]

How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the font family of the nav menu and sub menu items use this selector to change both at the same time:

```
.main-navigation ul {
    font-family: (insert font here);
}
```

And to move the article post area down the page:

```
.site-main {
    margin: 80px 31.3% 0 0; //80px is the top margin. Adjust this to put it exactly where you want.
}
```

Make sure you use a child theme so when you update the Lovecraft theme your CSS is not overwritten.

To make it easier for us to answer questions like this in future you should have included a link to your website or if it is only hosted locally then a link to the same theme on Wordpress.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "make sure you use a child theme so when you update the Lovecraft theme your CSS is not overwritten."

Comment: @konstantin A child theme is basically a copy of your 'main' theme, but when there are updates to the 'main' theme, your child theme is not effected. It's good practice to use a child theme to avoid overwriting your changes. If the main theme gets updated, anything you edited on the main theme's files will be overwritten with the new content from the update. Hope this helps you understand, you can read more about it here - [Wordpress Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: @konstantin This code will still work with out creating a child theme but it is good practice to do so and will save you having to re write any custom CSS at a future date when the theme is updated.

Comment: I am using either the child or from the editor the main css file. I add the your code, try to play a little bit with the margin and the font, but couldnt see any result.